# how to use which.min() function in a dataframe

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a dataset with columns and rows and in that dataset I want to extract the minimum water potential value which i did by using the which.min() function which gave me the position of the element present in the data frame but other than that I want the species and the day for that value recorded which codes to use? I use something like this

`f[which.min(f$water_potential),]`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand it correctly you have a data frame, say `df`, and `which.min(df$water_potential)` returns you the position of the observation with the minimum value. What happens if you try something like

```
df[which.min(df$water_potential),]
```

to retrieve the other column values for this observation?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot that was helpful, but what if I just do which.min(df$water_potential)

Comment: It will return you the index of the observation (i.e. dataframe row) where the minimum is achieved. To make this more apparent, you could do it like this
`i <- which.min(df$water_potential)`, `min_water_observation <- df[i,]`